# Native Messaging in Webextension on Firefox Android is supported but how?

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

Firefox Android is my favorite mobile browser, due to the support of webextensions.

According to this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendNativeMessage#browser_compatibility) Native Messaging in Firefox Android > 68 is supported.

That's great, and even  greater if it could talk to Termux, but I can't find an example or any instructions how to make it work: where to put the manifest file or how to link to a native application.

Does anybody knows how Native Messaging should be done on Firefox Android?

Or is it not really supported, but only to allow the extension to install on Android, which IMHO did fail before.

Comment: If I got it right this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1518843) documents how native messaging was developed for Firefox Android. It seems what the developers had in mind... Seems like the recipient has to be an app implementing a special interface.

Comment: Sending message to Android app (native) is the problem. Ask at Firefox support or at Reddit (/r/firefox) to provide some sort of sample. Firefox devs visit these places so one of them might notice this. Besides, regular Firefox for Android is useless for this anyway because of addons restrictions. You'd have to use Nightly.

Comment: As a workaround, you can host a local webserver (preferably in Python) on Termux and send instructions to it from your Firefox Nightly. Of course, you'd have to write a webextension for this as well. But the communication would at least take place compared to native messaging. The webserver can invoke whatever you want Termux to do with the message.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the native app should implement something like [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/web-extensions.html).

Comment: There is no need to use Firefox Nightly, extensions are supported in [F-Droid Firefox version](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.mozilla.fennec_fdroid/)